# Access match a value to closest value in another table

Tags: ms-access, matching

Seen some things close but not exact, ill keep it basic.

2 tables

Table1
NAME    PERCENTAGE
Chris   56%
Jane    67%

Table 2
PERCENTAGE     VALUE
50%            £3
60%            £4
70%            £5

I want to return the value from table 2 where the percentage from table 1 matches to the closest value lower than the original value, not above.

Expected output:

NAME     PERCENTAGE    VALUE
Chris    56%           £3
Jane     67%           £4

Ideally in SQL not VBA and we want to run the DB from python and VBA won't run correctly.

Many thanks if you can help.

We can do this by creating a massive table and matching to every possible number but this is not ideal.

Comment: NAME and VALUE are reserved words. Advise not to use reserved words as names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to return the values needed. Something like:

```
SELECT 
M.FirstName, 
M.Percentage, 
(SELECT TOP 1 L.DataValue FROM tblLookup AS L WHERE L.Percentage<M.Percentage ORDER BY L.Percentage DESC) AS ReturnValue
FROM tblMain AS M;
```

You will need to ensure that there is a negative percentage value on the second table to cater for anybody having a percentage of 0 in the first table.

Comment: Perhaps use `<=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Super dooper thanks, can use this in multiple ways taaaaa